# PostGIS distance between multiple points

Tags: postgis, distance

I have a data set in a PostGIS data base (table name is animals) with the following structure:

```
id (int, pk) | latitude (double) | longitude (double) | type (char) | geom (srid: 4326)
```

In the type-column there are currently values of 1 and 2, where 1 stands for, let's say, lions and 2 for zebras.

I've managed to calculate the distances between all points with

```
SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(a.geom, b.geom)
FROM animals a, animals b
WHERE a.typ=' 1' AND b.typ=' 2';
```

However, I want to select all the attributes where the distance is smaller than 500 m. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE (ST_Distance_Sphere(a.geom, b.geom)
FROM animals a, animals b
WHERE a.typ=' 1' AND b.typ=' 2') < 500;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM animals a, animals b
WHERE a.typ=' 1' AND b.typ=' 2'
AND ST_Distance_Sphere(a.geom, b.geom) < 500;
```

Comment: Thanks! Should have putten a little more effort in that myself, wasn't so difficult after all!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`ST_DWithin` for `geography`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html), e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM animals a, animals b
WHERE a.typ=' 1' AND b.typ=' 2'
AND ST_DWithin(a.geom::geography, b.geom::geography, 500.0, FALSE);
```

Where the last parameter is `use_spheroid:=FALSE` to use a faster sphere calculation method. This method can be optimized using geography indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX animals_geog_idx ON animals USING gist ((geom::geography));
```